NASA Mars Rover Photo APl mission manifest endpoint returning Error 500
I am trying to use NASA's Mars Rover Photos API to access the mission manifest endpoint.
The other endpoints seem to be working fine, but when I query for the latest mission manifest, I get an error 500 response. Here's the code for my API request:
def get_photos():
    # get today's date 
    date = (datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

    # Define the endpoint and parameters
    url = f'https://api.nasa.gov/mars-photos/api/v1/manifest/perseverance?api_key={api_key}'
    params = {
        'earth_date': date,
        'api_key': api_key,
    }

    # Send the request to the API
    response = requests.get(url, params=params)
    print("Response received...")
    print(f"response: {response}")
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print("Response 200 OK")
    else:
        print(f'ERROR: {response.status_code} - {response.reason}')

This is what I get:
Response received...
response: Internal Server Error
ERROR: 500 - Internal Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\avahe\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 974, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_3.12.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\avahe\OneDrive\Desktop\flask_app_good\curiosity_test.py", line 39, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\Users\avahe\OneDrive\Desktop\flask_app_good\curiosity_test.py", line 36, in main
    get_photos()
  File "c:\Users\avahe\OneDrive\Desktop\flask_app_good\curiosity_test.py", line 26, in get_photos
    data = response.json()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\avahe\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.12_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python312\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 978, in json
    raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Does anyone know how to fix this?

you're printing the entire response, so: what's in it? [edit] your post to include the full error, and any other pertinent details you're printing.

A HTTP status code of 500 usually means that their server is faulty. Since this is a GET request, you could also enter it in your browser and see what happens.

You could also try to remove ?api_key=... from your URL and put it into params dict instead. params will basically become ?key=value.

@Green绿色 I still get HTTP ERROR 500 when I open it in my browser

Are you behind a company proxy or is there anything that may intercept the traffic? If not, you probably wait a bit until NASA fixes their server or you submit a ticket.

@Green绿色 I've noticed that the mission manifest data attached to a normal response:
` "rover": {
    "id": 8,
    "name": "Perseverance",
    "landing_date": "2021-02-18",
    "launch_date": "2020-07-30",
    "status": "active",
    "max_sol": 1304,
    "max_date": "2024-10-19",
    "total_photos": 244058,`

I think I'll just get the manifest data from there instead. Thanks for your help!
